# Employer asking private questions (real estate, family, ...)

Tags: interviewing, human-resources, germany, switzerland

Is it normal for HR to ask an employee (without a valid business reason) if they expect reduced flexibility at work due to family plans or plans to purchase a property?

Is it advisable to docuemnt when and by whom these questions were asked? This is not the first misstep that the HR made.

I was asked this question as part of the evaluation for possible promotion opportunities.

Background information: I am working in programming industry in Germany/Switzerland for a typical office work. We don't have emergencies or risk for conflict of interest when owning a property.

Comment: What country are you in, and what industry?  In many countries these questions may be illegal.  However, in some industries they may be necessary to comply with conflict-of-interest laws.

Comment: I am now almost sure that these questions were illegal. The follow-up question is how to react.

Comment: @LuMu What is the end goal you want to achieve?

Comment: In Switzerland things work a bit differently than in Germany

Comment: You are begging the question by inserting "Without a valid business reason"

Comment: Where is the company/HR located? Germany or Switzerland?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question about family planning is illegal in Germany. You cannot sue anybody, but since not answering the question would be a disadvantage in the interview, you are allowed to *lie*. If your future employer asks you whether you are pregnant (or "plan to start a family") you can keep a straight face and say no, even in cases where you already know you are.

The only exception to this is if the employer has a "berechtigtes Interesse" (legitimate interest). The only legitimate interest in this case is if the employer is trying to fill a temporary vacancy for an employee that is on pregnancy leave. As employer, you are allowed to get a temporary replacement for your pregnant employee that is not pregnant and unavailable for the same timespan themselves.

The second question about the property is not exactly illegal, but certainly worth raising eyebrows. It might not be advisable to flat out lie, but as long as you can say "well, in the interview I thought I'd never buy property, but the month after, I changed my mind", you should be fine to just go with what they want to hear.

If you are applying for a leadership position (not just teamlead or project manager, but something C-level) questions trying to find your personal wealth are allowed.

To sum it up, for a normal position that is neither a stand-in for someone on pregnancy leave or a C-level position, both questions are highly questionable. Not only because they should not be asked, but HR *knows* they should not be asked and did it anyway, *or* is highly incompetent.

What to do? Lie. That is the official, covered by the courts position on this question.

Comment: How to know in which direction to lie? I could make a case for saying yes to both would make you less of a flight risk.

Comment: @lijat The fact that they ask these questions at all implies that HR is either clueless or malicious so one should not bet on them acting in either your or even their best interest when presented with this kind of information. Best to just stick with the status quo.

Comment: Well, for the pregnancy question it's clear: say no. If they had any interest in creating a good environment for family planning, they would know to not ask such a question, but instead praise their own advantages concerning parental leave, maybe a company kindergarden, or other support. For the property question, I don't know. If they want to sent you on long trips overseas they might look for a candidate that has no ties locally. If they are looking to hire for the long term, they might be happy to hear you own property close by and are unlikely to move. Go with your gut, but do not lie.

Comment: I want to point out that lying to your company is not a good way to form a relationship, especially in Germany where people have long memories and many industries are community based. If you burn your bridges in one company, no other company in the same industry will have anything to do with you.

Comment: Uh... you did read my full answer, right? I'm only talking about answers to *illegal* questions in an interview, where lying is *the court approved method* of responding. I think we are past "a good relationship" when it starts with the company asking illegal questions.

Answer (score 5):

### I'll take the dissenting answer: what they did might *not* be illegal/wrong.

Granted, I'm basing this off the way OP phrased their post, but here's the part I'm going off of:

> "[Do you] expect reduced flexibility at work due to family plans or
> plans to purchase a property?"

Note that the question is **not** 'Do you have a family', 'Are you trying to start a family', 'Are you purchasing a new home', etc, etc.

The question is actually: Do you expect that you'll have scheduling demands that would prevent regular hours?  In other words, the answer is simply one of these two:

- No.  I can't see any reason why I'd be prevented working a regular schedule.
- Yes.  (And then feel free to add any details on expected irregularity length.)

Don't get me wrong.  They're likely *hoping* you'll go into depth on issues they're not allowed to legally ask about.  But... technically, they're not asking you anything personal.  They're just asking whether you anticipate needing scheduling considerations.

Comment: This is spot on.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in theory companies are not supposed to be making hiring and promotional decisions based on factors like whether you have children or not, but in reality some companies do anyway, especially if they are smaller, because they do not want to be in a situation where a critical employee suddenly is absent for a year to take care of a baby.

You can say whatever you want, but at the end of the day if you want a family-friendly work environment, it sounds like you probably will not find it at your current company.

Comment: And not just a baby, even someone with actual children is less likely to come in early or work after hours than someone without kids.